# c++ project, vs2010, "build failed" with no errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a new c++ cli project in visual studio 2010.
After i create the new project, i try to build it, and get "build failed" message, with no errors, or other description of what went wrong

1>------ Build started: Project: TestProject3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I am working on windows 7, 64 bit.

This is happening also if i try to create the project with another template (like win32 console application).

I tried to create the project under "c:\Test", to make sure that the problem is not with the folder's path, or write permissions.

This solution also contains a c# project, that is working with no problems.

Does anyone know this problem? do i need to change something in the project properties?
Thanks in advance :)
Amir

Comment: usually the c: root folder needs Administrator's permission to write files in this case the exe generated program, i think you should execute the visual Studio with righ click execute as an administrator

Comment: Thank you for the help...

I tried, and still the same "build failed" message.
It is happening also when i save the project in "c:\users\amir\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects"

Answer (score 0):

Did you include any source files to be built? It would seem natural that compilation fails without any errors only when there are no source files (included for build) or they are empty, perhaps.

Comment: The clr class library template create one header and one cpp automaticlly with this code:

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace TestProject3 {

 public ref class Class1
 {

 };
}

It fails to compile even when i write some code in this class...